# Trying to convert int to string without using in-built function in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def int_to_str(num):
    is_negative = False
    if num:
        num, is_negative = -num, True
    s = []
    while True:
        s.append(chr(ord('0') + num % 10))
        num //= 10
        if num == 0:
            break
    return ('-' if is_negative else '') + ''.join(reversed(s))
num = input("Enter any numeric value: ")
print(int_to_str(num))
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: it doesnt print anything after I enter the no. eg. 25

Comment: Instead of `break`, you can just use `while num`.

Comment: @tobias_k if you do `while num`, then an input of 0 will not add any characters to s.

Comment: my original code has num < 0 and taking user input num and converting it into int() before passing as arg. Somehow It didnt reflect. Even after that changes, the program doesnt work.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the guidelines there to refine your question with additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only an integer in the conditional of an if statement, the if statement will run if and only if the integer is not equal to zero. You need to do

```
if num < 0:
```

not

```
if num:
```

But indeed, @user8145959 has a point. The number inputted is already a string. When you pass the input string to int_to_str, it gets automatically converted to an integer at the places where you try integer operations on it.

Edit: Automatic integer conversion works only in python 2, not python 3. My mistake.

Edit2: Actually I'm just wrong. Didn't realize `input()` did the conversion already.

Comment: I would upvote for the first part, but the last sentence is wrong. Python does not silently convert a string to an int when it encounters an int-operation. It will raise an Exception.

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks, but it actually does in python 2. When I got an exception when trying to run his code in python 3, I assumed he was developing in python 2 and when I tried that instead I got no error. So my observation was made assuming python 2. Post updated to reflect that fact.

Comment: Even in Python 2, strings that contain numbers are not automatically converted to integers when you "try integer operations on it". `"42" % 10` is an error in both, Python 2 and 3. What Python 2 does is that `input` will automatically evaluate `"42"` as a python expression and thus return the int `42`

Comment: @tobias_k Oh, you're correct. My apologies. For some reason I swore I tried testing `print("99" % 10)` in python 2 with it working, now I actually tried that and it failed.

Answer (score 1):

```
The idea is to use the ASCII value of the digits from 0 to 9 start from 48 – 57.
```

```
num = 56

s = [0 if not num else '']
while num:
    s.append(chr(48 + num % 10))
    num = num // 10
a= "".join(reversed(s))

print(a)
print(type(a))

output->
56
<class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [chr()](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#chr) and [ord()](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#ord) just like you did:

```
def int_to_str(input_int):
    if input_int < 0:
        is_negative = True
        input_int *= -1
    else:
        is_negative = False

    output_str = []
    while input_int > 0:
        # print(input_int % 10)
        output_str.append(chr(ord("0") + input_int % 10))
        input_int //= 10

    output_str = "".join(output_str[::-1])
    if is_negative:
        return "-" + output_str
    else:
        return output_str


print(int_to_str(123))
print(int_to_str(-123))
```

```
>>> "123"
>>> "-123"
```

Answer (score 0):

Python takes input as a string
So you do not need to write a function for it
When you take input num
It is already a string

Comment: I know but i dnt want to use any in-built functions like int() or str() to convert

Comment: According​ to the code you have given you dont need to convert
If you ask that how to convert int to string in python thats different but taking input and converting to string is not required because its already a string
To improve you should write
Num=int(input....

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn't work because you're doing a couple of things wrong. First, it will crash on the tagged `python-3.x` as it doesn't evaluate the input so you're essentially passing a string to your function as `input()` returns a string. You should use:

```
num = int(input("Enter any numeric value: "))  # and you should use raw_input() on Python 2.x
```

instead. You may want to validate the input first, too, to make sure that the integer was selected. Second, it always declares your `num` as negative as `if num:` will always return True for every value other than `0`, so use `if num < 0:` instead.

Also, you're adding more conditions to it than needed, you can use your value in the `while` statement directly, i.e.:

```
s = [0 if not num else '']
while num:
    s.append(chr(48 + num % 10))
    num //= 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def int_to_str(num):
    s = []
    while True:
            digit = num % 10
            num = num // 10
            if digit == num: # or we could also use digit == 0 condition 
                break
            s.append(chr(ord('0') + digit))
    return ''.join(s[::-1])
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Code only is not very useful

Answer (score 0):

Solution using recursion.

```
def integer_to_string(i):

    # Edge case
    if i == 0:
        return chr(i+48)

    # Handling negative number
    negative_integer = False
    if i < 0:
        negative_integer = True
        i = - i

    def convert_to_string(i):
        if i < 10:
            return chr(i+48)
        else:
            return (convert_to_string(i // 10)) + chr((i%10)+48)

    result = convert_to_string(i)

    if negative_integer:
        return '-' + result
    else:
        return result
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work for you

```
def int_to_str(num):
is_negative = False
if num:
    num, is_negative = num, True
s = []
while True:
    s.append(chr(ord('0') + num % 10))
    num //= 10
    if num == 0:
        break
return ''.join(reversed(s))
```

Comment: You have a compilation error which will not work the error will be:
'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
on if num: